# How to use a single function to enumerate these data structures in c#?

Tags: c#

I have some data structures which contain information like 'Tcpv4Endpoint' and 'TCPV6Endpoint' .

The data structures are :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID
{
    public uint state;
    public uint localAddr;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public byte[] localPort;
    public uint remoteAddr;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public byte[] remotePort;
    public uint owningPid;
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MIB_TCP6ROW_OWNER_PID
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
    public byte[] localAddr;
    public uint localScopeId;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public byte[] localPort;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
    public byte[] remoteAddr;
    public uint remoteScopeId;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public byte[] remotePort;
    public uint state;
    public uint owningPid;
}
```

As you can imagine, I use these 2 data structures in two different functions to populate the list view. I wanted to combine the addition of these 2 structures into one common function. But I cannot figure out how to make a typecast between these 2 structures and access the fields too.

The function I want to generalize is something like this :

```
public void addTCPV6ConnectionsToListView()
{
    int i;
    string strErrorMessage = "";
    List<MIB_TCP6ROW_OWNER_PID> tcpRowTable = ...//data populated...//
    MIB_TCP6ROW_OWNER_PID row;

    //...Error handling case removed for ease of reading ...  
    ListViewItem[] lItem = new ListViewItem[tcpRowTable.Count];
    listView1.BeginUpdate();
    for (i = 0; i < tcpRowTable.Count; i++)
    {
        row = tcpRowTable[i];
            lItem[i].Text = Process.GetProcessById((int)row.ProcessId).ProcessName + ".exe";
        lItem[i].SubItems.Add(row.ProcessId.ToString());
        lItem[i].SubItems.Add("TCPV6");
        lItem[i].SubItems.Add("[ " + expandCompressedIPv6Addr(row.LocalAddress.ToString()) + " ]"); //Similiar fields in TCPv4 and TCPv6 structures , except for one or two fields
        lItem[i].SubItems.Add(row.LocalPort.ToString());
        lItem[i].SubItems.Add("[ " + expandCompressedIPv6Addr(row.RemoteAddress.ToString()) + " ]");
        lItem[i].SubItems.Add(row.RemotePort.ToString());
        lItem[i].SubItems.Add(getStateInformation(row.State));
    }
    listView1.Items.AddRange(lItem);
    listView1.EndUpdate();

}
```

Is it possible to do this ?

Comment: Can you define an interface that applies to both? Something like IMibOwnerPid that defines the properties in common to both. Then your List could be a List<IMibOwnerPid>.

Comment: @MichaelWelch : its a good idea, let me try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be to define a common interface.

```
public interface MIB_OWNER_PID
{
    public uint state {get; set; }
    public uint localAddr { get; set; }
    public byte[] localPort { get; set; }
    public uint remoteAddr { get; set; }
    public byte[] remotePort { get; set; }
    public uint owningPid { get; set; }
}
```

With this solution you have to keep in mind that interfaces can only define **properties**, not fields. So you have to change the fields you defined to properties:

Instead of

```
public uint state;
```

write

```
public uint state { get; set;}
```

---

Another option would be to simply cast the objects to `dynamic` before using them. Then you can use any property, field or method, the compiler doesnt complain, because they are evaluated at **runtime**. So if the property, field or method doesnt exist at runtime, you will still get an exception.

```
dynamic row = tcpRowTable[i];
lItem[i].SubItems.Add("[ " + expandCompressedIPv6Addr(row.RemoteAddress.ToString()) + " ]");
```

Comment: Accepted due to the easy 'dynamic' option given, my code was already large, and did not want to break anything by using interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your specfic [StructLayout] is because you also want/need to be able to support memcpy type of operations. If that's the case you could add methods/properties before your specific field in combination with an interface.

```
public interface MIB_OWNER_PID
{
   public void update (uint state,uint localaddr, byte[] localport, /*etc*/)
   public uint localAddress { get; set; }
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID : MIB_OWNER_PID
{
   public uint state;
   public uint localAddr;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
   public byte[] localPort;
   public uint remoteAddr;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
   public byte[] remotePort;
   public uint owningPid;

   public void update (uint state,uint localaddr, byte[] localport, /*etc*/)
   {

   }

   public uint localAddress 
   {
      get { return localAddr;} 
      set { localAddr = value}
    }
}
```

Be casefull with using 'simple' properties with an empty {get; set;} because you might not have control anymore about how the backingfields are generated.

The advantage of using methods on your structs is that you can reply on polimorphism to 'do the right thing' and implement both the ipv4 and ipv6 way. (as long as the methods have the same signature. if you rely in ipv6 specific fields then this doesn't work well).